How to configure serilog using .json configuration file to avoid the messages from HttpClientFactory?
I have an application that use HttpClientFactory to create a HttpClient to makes requests.
I would like to avoid to log the information messages from HttpClient and HttpClientFactory.
To avoid messages from HttpClient in serilog, I have this configuration in the appsettings.json file:
"Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Verbose",
    "Override": {
      "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Warning"
    }
  },

This solve the messages when I do a request with the http client.
However, I am still having this messages:
11:00:50 DBG] HttpMessageHandler expired after 120000ms for client ''
[11:01:00 DBG] Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 1 items
[11:01:00 DBG] Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0323ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 1 items
[11:01:10 DBG] Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 1 items
[11:01:10 DBG] Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0037ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 1 items
[11:01:20 DBG] Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 1 items
[11:01:20 DBG] Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0025ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 1 items
[11:01:30 DBG] Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 1 items
[11:01:30 DBG] Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0034ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 1 items
[11:01:40 DBG] Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 1 items
[11:01:40 DBG] Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0037ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 1 items
[11:01:50 DBG] Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 1 items
[11:01:50 DBG] Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0033ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 1 items

If I am not wrong, this messages come from the HttpClientFactory when it handles the life cycle of the HttMessageHandlers.
How could I avoid to log this in a similar way I avoid to log the messages from the HttpClient?

These messages are logged by the DefaultHttpClientFactory.
So, if you don't want to see these messages then set the minimum log level to Information for the DefaultHttpClientFactory:
"Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory": "Information"

As you can see the DefaultHttpClientFactory resides inside the Microsoft.Extensions.Http namespace, not under the System.Net.Http like the HttpClient.
